# roscd and roslaunch problem

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roscd, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use roscd and roslaunch and press tab, I got the following error msgs:

```
rospack: error while loading shared libraries: librospack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
rosstack: error while loading shared libraries: librospack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the same condition happen when I do roslaunch.

I've already source the setup.bash in my bashrc. But if I source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash again manually, everything works fine. I've never met with this problem in other computers. All I need to do is just source the setup.bash in bashrc and then roscd and roslaunch works fine in every new terminal.

My platform is Ubuntu 12.10 , ROS Groovy, and install using apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67073/roscd-and-roslaunch-problem/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-10**:
I don't understand : did you add this line in your bashrc before you got the error and your problem is that apparently the sourcing failed or did you add it to your bashrc after, when you noticed it solved your problem (and then your problem is solved) ?

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-07-11**:
I already add this line in my bashrc. And then I try to use roscd and roslaunch, I got the error. But if I source the setup.bash again, it works. In other computer I don't have to source it manually again in every new terminal. I just need to add this line and then roscd and roslaunch work fine.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-11**:
You must have something else in you bashrc file which manipulates the environment or not source the file in the bashrc file correctly. Otherwise there is no rational why sourcing it twice would make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `/opt/ros/groovy/lib` (where the related dynamic library files are stored). If not, check all setup scripts you're using to see if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gets overwritten after ROS' `setup.bash` is called.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-07-11**:
Yeah, it's overwritten by other settings! May I ask that what is the purpose of these setup.bash files? I have to source it in /opt/ros/groovy when I install ROS, and when I create a catkin worksapce I have to source the one in devel, and even when I create an overlay workspace I have to source it.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-17**:
That's worth a whole new question (esp. to get better answers than what I could offer).

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-21**:
In `~/.bashrc` I had used `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path` when I should have used `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`